# How to upload image to imgur album?

Tags: javascript, shared-hosting, imgur

I would like to upload image to own album by using javascript.

This code can upload image to imgur, but I dont know how to upload it to my album.

http://jsfiddle.net/FGxGg/57/

```
$.ajax({
url: "https://api.imgur.com/3/upload",
type: "POST",
datatype: "json",
data: {image: imgUrl},
success: showMe,
error: showMe,
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Client-ID " + clientId);
}});
```

Or any suggestion for image hosting to own album?

Comment: I personally use GoogleDrive with a shared folder and 'move' everything to that folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imgur has [detailed API documentation](http://api.imgur.com/endpoints) on all their endpoints, including **[Image Upload](http://api.imgur.com/endpoints/image#image-upload)**.

According to the documentation, you can supply an `album` parameter with the `id` of the album you want to upload to.  So, change your data to include it:

```
var clientId = ""; // Your client Id
var imgUrl = "http://i.imgur.com/l5OqYoZ.jpg";
var albumId = 'ABC123'; // Your owned album id

$.ajax({
  url: "https://api.imgur.com/3/upload",
  type: "POST",
  datatype: "json",
  data: {image: imgUrl, album: albumId},
  success: showMe,
  error: showMe,
  beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Client-ID " + clientId);
}});
```

Comment: Thanks, its work... and need to change the request header to xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Bearer access_token');

Comment: But I having the extract access token problem.
Do you know how to solve it?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38140521/ajax-how-to-get-the-returned-url-or-set-cookie

Comment: I am trying to implement the same using python api, authentication seems to be failing. Any clue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50385846